# Using Markov's inequality to show that probability converges

Tags: random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 2}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that

$X_n = n $ with probability $\frac{1}{2n \log(n)}$

$X_n = -n$ with probability $\frac{1}{2n \log(n)}$

$X_n = 0$ with probability $1-\frac{1}{n \log(n)}$

Let S := $X_2 + ... + X_{n+1}$.

Why does it hold that for every $\epsilon > 0$ , $\mathbb P( | \frac{S_n}{n} - \mathbb E[\frac{S_n}{n}] | > \epsilon) \to 0$?

I thought that the Markov's inequality $\mathbb P( | \frac{S_n}{n} | > \epsilon) \leq \frac{\mathbb E[ | \frac{S_n}{n} |^2]}{\epsilon^2}$ would help, but does it really...?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $X_0$ and $X_1$ are not defined.

Comment: S is defined as starting from $X_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Chebyshev's inequality:

$$P(|S_n/n-\mu_n|>\epsilon)\leq \frac{\mbox{Var}(S_n/n)}{\epsilon^2}=\frac{\sum_{k=2}^n n/\log(n)}{\epsilon^2n^2}=...$$

Comment: @Stacker: thanks, corrected.

Comment: Thanks for this hint! :) It helped a lot.